# how toggleClass work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have interesting problem with toggleClass();

I got 5 input image elements and I want to do switch image (input src) using toggleClass but I don't understand why toggleClass is not doing that I want to do ?

```js
$(".form-elements input[type='button']").on("click", function() {
 
  var el = $(this).attr("class");
 if(el=="d1"){
   $(".d1").toggleClass('d1 d1_pasif');
  
}else if(el=="d2"){
  
 $(".d2").toggleClass('d2 d2_pasif');
 
}else if(el=="d3"){
   
  $(".d3").toggleClass('d3 d3_pasif');

}else if(el=="d4"){
  
  $(".d4").toggleClass('d4 d4_pasif'); 
 
 } else if(el=="d5"){
   
  $(".d5").toggleClass('d5 d5_pasif');
  
 }
  return false; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-elements">
  <input type="image" name="d5" class="d5" src="http://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d5.png" />
  <input type="image" name="d4" class="d4" src="http://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d4.png" />
  <input type="image" name="d3" class="d3" src="http://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d3.png" />
  <input type="image" name="d2" class="d2" src="http://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d2.png" />
  <input type="image" name="d1" class="d1" src="http://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d1.png" />
</div>
```

I have a and b images,
When I click a image it has to be b images and when I click b images it has to be a images.

thanks.

Comment: `toggleClass` toggles classes, not attributes like src.

Comment: Just read [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: oooh I didn't know thanks..but how to do that I want ?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Comment: friends thanks I understand but is there any way to do ? switch input images ?

Comment: @ani_css: There are lots of ways you could approach it. You could check the current `src` attribute for the `_pasif.png` ending and if it's there, remove it, if it's not, add it.

Comment: @MattBurland I edited my JS codes I did it but not switch ,after img changed second click must be default img ?

Comment: @ani_css: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: You should be checking `if($(...).hasClass(...))` before you run `$(this).addClass(...)` or it will always have that class.

Comment: When you edit the code in the question, you should also edit the title and explanation. If you're not using `toggleClass` anywhere in the code, why do you still ask about it in the title?

Comment: @MattBurland I mean; I have a and b images, When I click a image it has to be b images and when I click b images it has to be a images.

Comment: @ani_css: And I gave you some code for one way you could do that. Put it in the click handler. You need to figure out what the current image is (by looking at the `src`) and then figure out which one you need to change it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```js
$(".form-elements input[type='image']").on("click", function() {
  var currSrc = $(this).attr("src");
  // check if the source ends with "_pasif.png"
  if (/_pasif.png$/.test(currSrc)) {
    // if it does, just replace it with ".png"
    $(this).attr("src", currSrc.replace(/_pasif.png$/, ".png"));
  } else {
    // if it does not, replace ".png" with "_pasif.png"
    $(this).attr("src", currSrc.replace(/.png$/, "_pasif.png"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-elements">
  <input type="image" name="d5" class="d5" src="http://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d5.png" />
  <input type="image" name="d4" class="d4" src="http://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d4.png" />
  <input type="image" name="d3" class="d3" src="http://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d3.png" />
  <input type="image" name="d2" class="d2" src="http://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d2.png" />
  <input type="image" name="d1" class="d1" src="http://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d1.png" />
</div>
```

Basically you test if the current src ends with `_pasif.png` and if it does, you set the `src` to the src without that `_pasif` part. If it doesn't you add it. Each click would then toggle from one to the other. And if all the buttons are following the same naming convention, you don't even need to worry about which button you are actually handling since all you are doing is replacing part of the `src` (so I don't care if it's `d1`, `d2`, or `d3`...)

Answer (score 0):

please find [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bluedextermini/hp4j4yud/27/) similar to what solution you are looking for, just play around it.

If you're wanting to style the button using CSS, make it a type="submit" button instead of type="image". type="image" expects a SRC, which you can't set in CSS.

Code snippet are as follow :

```js
$(".form-elements input[type='button']").on("click", function() {
  debugger;
  var el = $(this).attr("class");
  //if(el=="d1"){
  $(this).toggleClass('d1 d1_pasif');
  //}

  return false;
});
```

```css
.d1 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d1_pasif.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
.d1_pasif {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d1.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-elements">
  <input type="image" name="d5" class="d5" src="https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d5.png" />
  <input type="image" name="d4" class="d4" src="https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d4.png" />
  <input type="image" name="d3" class="d3" src="https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d3.png" />
  <input type="image" name="d2" class="d2" src="https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d2.png" />
  <input type="button" name="d1" class="d1" />

</div>
```

Comment: heey it's great but if I set if conditional my codes are not work for 

I edited my JS codes you can see above